# OpenLayers 3 Map center is not getting set at New Jersey

Tags: openlayers

Map is not getting set at center location.

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        url: 'njcitypolygonv2.geojson'
    }),
    style: function(feature, resolution) {
        style.getText().setText( feature.get('city') );
        return styles;
    }
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
        //source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
        }),
    vectorLayer
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([40.0000, 74.5000], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 3
    })
});
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
center: ol.proj.transform([-74.5, 40], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
```